# random array values in java

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

I have to create a program that populates an array with 50 random values between 1 and 100, then have the user input a number between 1 and 100. The program will then output how many times that number appeared in the array. Here is what I have so far, I am not sure what to do next in order to complete my program.

```
    import java.util.*;

public class Occurences {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //This program will generate an array with 50 random values
    //This user will then input a number
    //The program will then tell the user how many times their numbers appears

    //Create array
    int numbers[]= new int[50];

    //Create a new scanner object
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 and 100");
    int Usernum= sc.nextInt();

    for (int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++)
    {
        numbers[i]=(int)(Math.random()*100+1);

    }

}

}
```

Comment: create a new loop and check whether `userNum` is equal to the value in `numbers[i]` if so increment a counter

Answer (score 2):

The pre Java 8 way to handle this would be to just iterate over the array of random numbers and count how many times the input occurred.  Add the following code:

```
int count = 0;
for (int i=0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (numbers[i] == Usernum) {
        ++count;
    }
}
System.out.println("The user input " + Usernum + " occurred " + count + " times.");
```

In Java 8 we can try using a stream on your array of random numbers:

```
int count = Arrays.stream(numbers).filter(x -> x == Usernum).toArray().length;
```

Comment: Thank you! This one really helped

Answer (score 1):

The code:

```
package com.stackoverflow.json;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //This program will generate an array with 50 random values
    //This user will then input a number
    //The program will then tell the user how many times their numbers appears

    //Create array
    int numbers[]= new int[50];

    //Create a new scanner object
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 and 100");
    int Usernum= sc.nextInt();

    for (int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++)
    {
        numbers[i]=ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 100 + 1);;

    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
    int count=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if(numbers[i]==Usernum)
            count++;
    }
    System.out.println("count="+count);

}

}
```

Prints:

```
Please enter a number between 1 and 100
2
[91, 12, 7, 55, 73, 77, 92, 69, 84, 49, 8, 54, 24, 27, 51, 84, 71, 79, 91, 65, 41, 30, 91, 2, 99, 83, 46, 31, 21, 17, 78, 18, 54, 48, 100, 9, 74, 8, 48, 63, 49, 89, 80, 22, 10, 79, 67, 84, 57, 17]
count=1
```